# How to handle nested field with arguments in Spring for GraphQL @Controller

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-graphql

Using `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-graphql` and WebMvc, I would like to handle, in the `@Controller`, nested fields with arguments.
E.g.:

```
query myQuery {
  field1(param1: "value1") {
    field2(param2: "value2") {
      field3
    }
  }
}
```

The `@Controller` handles the first field with:

```
@QueryMapping
public Field1 field1(@Argument param1) {...}
```

But how to handle the second level field with argument?

Comment: How to handle 3rd level assuming object is.

query myQuery {
  field1(param1: "value1") {
    field2(param2: "value2") {
      field3 { abc, xyz }
    }
  }
}

Answer (score 1):

I solved it using `@SchemaMapping`:

```
@QueryMapping
public Field1 field1(@Argument param1) {...}

@SchemaMapping
public Field2 field2(Field1 field1, @Argument param2) {...}
```